# How to read a file from another server in java?

Tags: java

I want to read a file from a server which is in the different location.

I have an IP, username and password of the server.

How can i read a file in java?

Comment: It depends what protocol are you going to use. Is this an FTP enabled server? Is this a web server? Anything else?

Answer (score 3):

- You can create a local FTP server and read remote file as byte array something like this

  ```
  try {
          URL url = new URL("ftp://localhost/myDir/fileOne.txt");
          InputStream is = url.openStream();
          ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                 
          byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
          int n;                  
          while ((n = is.read(buf)) >= 0) 
                  os.write(buf, 0, n);
          os.close();
          is.close();                     
          byte[] data = os.toByteArray();
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
  ```
- Read the binary file through Http

  ```
  URL url = new URL("http://q.com/fileOne.txt");             
  InputStream is = url.openStream();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use Java, you should just use scp.

If there is a need to do this from Java, you can always form your scp command as a string and pass it to Runtime.getRuntime.exec().  (Be careful with passwords in your source code, though.)

Comment: But that would execute outside of JVM.